# GoDaddy subdomain limit reached trigger

Tags: subdomain, godaddy

Is there a way to know beforehand, like a trigger per se, that you are about to reach the subdomain limit or that you have reached the subdomain limit for goDaddy?

Comment: So you can't count the subdomains in the control panel?

Comment: I can, But I need a trigger for my backend team to know.